# React cloneNode - make a copy

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to do a cloneNode in React?

At its basic level, what I wanted to do was click on the component, and then have it make a copy of that component for me to use. I eventually want to do a simple copy drag and then drop but I just wanted to know how to do a clone of the component/element.

Is there a better way to go about this? The component will be static, and then a simple click would clone it or dynamically created for use.

```
var TestChild = React.createClass({
    onClick: function (e) {
        this.props.onClick(e);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.onClick}>Test Item</div>
        )
    }
});

var TestParent = React.createClass({
    onClick: function (e) {
        // cloneNode
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <TestChild onClick={this.onClick} />
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: React has `cloneElement` method - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement, you can try use it

Answer (score 0):

What about keeping a state in parent element `TestParent` denoting how many child element `TestChild` now should be there, like `this.state.count`, then in parent's `render` method, map the state to `TestChild`s. And the `onClick` function just increment the counter. Here is an [example](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children) from the React docs

Comment: @fes just update the `count` variable by calling `this.setState` in `onClick` event handler, and the `render()` function will be called automatically to re-render the components with the new `count`

Comment: On the onclick the component gets added but is there anyway to pass the current mouse event and pass it to the new component? I wanted to do a mousedown on the component (done) -> new component is created (after re-render) (done) -> mousedown is now on new component -> I can now control the new component. I've been trying to work out how to do the last two steps.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what you want to do exactly but what about referencing your child component and then using [cloneElement()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html?#cloneelement), so something like this.

```
var TestChild = React.createClass({
    onClick: function (e) {
        this.props.onClick(e);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.onClick}>Test Item</div>
        )
    }
});

var TestParent = React.createClass({
    onClick: function (e) {
        const newEl = React.cloneElement(this.myRef, {});
        // then you do whatever you need to do with your new copy of TestChild component
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <TestChild onClick={this.onClick} ref={this.myRef} />
        )
    }
});
```

Maybe this helps?